# Error with wilcox_effsize(): no applicable method for 'pull' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Tags: r

I am trying to compute the effect size of a one-sample Wilcoxon test.

The complete dataset is stored in the sart variable. The data in question is stored in the variable `Delta_PI`, which is a list of numerical values ranging between `-1` and `1`.

The test runs without problems, and I would like to find the effect size. Hence, I use:

```r
install.packages("coin")
library("coin")
install.packages("rstatix")
library("rstatix")

wilcox_effsize(sart$Delta_PI, Delta_PI ~ 1,alternative = "greater",
               mu=0)
```

Noting that the `alternative = "greater"` goes back to my alternative hypothesis (`mu_DeltaPI >0`).

When I run the command, however, I get the following error, which I don't understand:

```r
Error in UseMethod("pull") : 
  no applicable method for 'pull' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

I have checked similar issues on the web and on Stack, alas to no avail*. As per [no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590054/no-applicable-method-for-filter-applied-to-an-object-of-class-cdouble-n), I have tried to convert the `list` into a `character`, but still, no success. I've also tried to convert the list to a numeric value using:

```r
as.numeric(unlist(data))
```

, but this outputs the same error.

Please help! I a newbie to `R` (and to StackOverflow), and any light shedding would be greatly appreciated.

(*)This thread uses `pull()` directly, whereas this is somehow embedded in the `wilcox_effsize()` command: [How to fix: "no applicable method for 'pull'" (dplyr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56985120/how-to-fix-no-applicable-method-for-pull-dplyr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your data using `dput(sart)`.

Without your data, I guess the first argument for `wilcox_effsize()` should be a dataframe, but not a vector (note `sart$Delta_PI` returns a vector). Take a look at `?wilcox_effsize`.

Try the following code to see how it goes.

```
wilcox_effsize(sart, 
               Delta_PI ~ 1,
               alternative = "greater",
               mu=0)
```

## Example using `mtcars`

```
wilcox_effsize(mtcars, 
               wt ~ 1,
               alternative = "greater",
               mu=0)

# A tibble: 1 x 6
  .y.   group1 group2     effsize     n magnitude
* <chr> <chr>  <chr>        <dbl> <int> <ord>    
1 wt    1      null model   0.873    32 large
```

Which seems to work.